# Membership.GetUser results In Object Reference Not Set to Instance Of An Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get the SQL results for the logged in user using:

```
// GET: /Incident/
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var loggedInUser = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString();
    var query = from b in db.Logs where b.Id == loggedInUser select b;
    return View(query.ToList());
}
```

But the first line of the method results in a NullReferenceException and I'm unsure why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current user is not logged on (or your membership provider doesn't believe the user is logged on), causing `GetUser()` method to return `null`, at which point you try to access `ProviderUserKey`, causing a `NullReference` exception.

You need to check `GetUser` returns you an `User` or `null`, and determine what to do from that point. You shouldn't assume that `GetUser` is going to return you a `user` object.

Comment: But if the user is logged in, why would it be null?

Comment: IF the user is logged in and your Membership Provider is telling you that the user is NOT logged in, then you have a problem with your Membership Provider itself. If that's the case, you need to go back over how you set it up and make sure all the information is correct.

Comment: The problem is not that `Membership.GetUser()` returns null, it's that the method itself throws a `NullReferenceException`. I arrived at this question trying to find and explanation for why it behaves that way instead of just returning null. (.NET Framework 4.7.2.) Specifically, it invokes `MemberShip.GetCurrentUserName()` and that's poorly implemented. It checks that the current `HttpContext` is not null, but then proceeds to access `User.Identity` with no null checks on either: `HttpContext current = HttpContext.Current; if (current != null) return current.User.Identity.Name;`

Answer (score 2):

You should check before calling that to see if the user is authenticated. if you are attempting to access that page before a user is actually logged in, then it would be null.

```
If(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
    //then get the users membership information
    }
```

Comment: What about if the user is not authenticated? The user is logged in at the point when I go to this method

Answer (score 0):

Using some overly defensive programming, try:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (Membership==null){
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Membership");
    }
    var user = Membership.GetUser();
    if (user ==null){
        throw new ArgumentNullException("User");
    }

    var loggedInUser = user.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
    if (loggedInUser ==null){
        throw new ArgumentNullException("loggedInUser ");
    }

    var query = from b in db.Logs where b.Id == loggedInUser select b;
    return View(query.ToList());
}
```

Comment: It throws an exception at GetUser()

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, `Membership.GetUser()` is just an example, that is where you need to stick your code to get the user from the DB or other store you are using.

Answer (score 0):

User.Identity.GetUserID is the way to get the user ID using ASP.Net MVC 5 auth

Answer (score -1):

I want to note a solution that worked for Me that applies generally to this question:

What: I was getting this error. I could see System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated  BUT... I wasn't logged in. Why?

Answer: I started letting people put in their email address OR username, then if email address I would authenticate using the username I pulled Using this email address. But guess what...

The "LOGIN CONTROL" (asp.net) itself STILL uses the FORMAL "username" field AS username no matter what you do in the authentication process SO you need to set the Username FIELD value ITSELF (before you e.authenticate) TO the pulled-username-you-got-from-the-email-they-typed in. Like this:

```
Dim IloginUsername As String = loginCONTROL.UserName

If iloginUsername.Contains("@") Then
        user_sayingtheyare = Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(iloginUsername)
        loginCONTROL.UserName = user_sayingtheyare '  KEY ADDITION

    Else
        user_sayingtheyare = iloginUsername
    End If
```